# Javascript Newb : How do I instantiate a var as "blah.1" and "blah.2"?

Tags: javascript

I currently have a block like this defining some vars

```
var slider_1  = document.querySelector('#slider_1');
var slider_2  = document.querySelector('#slider_2');
...
```

And func's that take ID's like this:

```
function updateFromInput(id){               
    if(id==1){
        var x = input_1.value*1;
        x = Math.round((x*ratio)-offset);     
        slider_1.x.baseVal.value =  x/scale;
    }else if(id==2){
        var x = input_2.value*1;
        x = Math.round((x*ratio)-offset); 
        slider_2.x.baseVal.value =  x/scale;
    }
};
```

I am trying to refactor a bit.
I'm thinking that if I could, instead, instantiate my vars with dots rather than underscores like

```
var slider.1  = document.querySelector('#slider_1');
var slider.2  = document.querySelector('#slider_2');
```

then I'd be able to better utilize the ID already getting passed into my func's and eliminate tons of duplication.
I was hoping to simplify my funcs with something like a single call for `slider.id.x.baseVal.value =  x/scale;` rather than having to have that code in **each** of the IF/ELSE conditions.

When I try that though, I get an error saying " *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number* ".
How *should* this be done?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a plain numeric key in an object.

You can do this, though:

```
var slider = {};  // or = [], if array syntax is more appropriate
slider[1] = ...
slider[2] = ...
```

Furthermore, the syntax you suggested isn't allowed if the key is actually a variable rather than a literal token.

In your example `slider.id` actually refers to the object with literal *key* `id`, not whatever value the *variable* `id` happens to have.

You have to put the variable inside square brackets, i.e. `slider[id]`, so your function would be written thus:

```
function updateFromInput(id){               
    var x = +input[id].value;
    x = Math.round((x*ratio)-offset);     
    slider[id].x.baseVal.value =  x/scale;
};
```

Comment: Could you not define the values inside the braces to be more concise? i.e. `var slider = { document.querySelector('#slider_1') };`

Comment: @Sam you'd still need to provide a key - i.e. `var slider = { '1': document.querySelector(...), '2': ... }`

Comment: I guess a list would be better then if you want to keep it short. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The `.` is an invalid character for a variable identifier.

You can use it in object properties though.

```
var sliders = {
    "slider.1": document.querySelector('#slider_1'),
    "slider.2": document.querySelector('#slider_2')
};
```

Then use the square bracket version of the member operator to access the property.

```
alert( sliders["slider.1"].id );
```